# Static link classes - need to know calling project name

Tags: c#, .net, static-linking

My Setup :

Project A

```
Class Log
{
  public static void WriteLog(string msg)
 {
    Trace.write(GetTimestamp(), GetAppDominNameCallingWriteLog(), msg);
 }
}
```

Project B 
 contains Static link Log.cs (Add as link)

Project C
contains Static link Log.cs (Add as link)

Project D
contains Static link Log.cs (Add as link)

Using one log file for all the project. Now I need to get the project name (`GetAppDominNameCallingWriteLog()`) in the `Log` class.  How can i achieve this without passing Project name to `WriteLog()`.

e.g. Project C calls `Log.Writelog("logging msg")` 
the result should be   201511121232  Project C  logging msg

Project D calls `Log.Writelog("logging msg")` 
the result should be   201511121232  Project D logging msg

Tried with `Thread.AppDomain()`, it always return Project A.

Sorry I forgot to add this case : Project C is referenced in  Project A.

Comment: I think you need to look at the [calling assembly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `AppDomain`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this case : Project C is referenced in  Project A. But still i need to get Project C in the log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out the executing project using the below code

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName;
```

I have also checked this with the Thread class. It returns the result correctly

```
System.Threading.Thread.GetDomain().FriendlyName;
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the additional information provided in the comments, you can identify the calling Assembly using Reflection

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName;
```

Working Example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Direct call to the Log class from ConsoleApplication3
        Log.Write();

        //Indirect call to the Log class through a Class Library called ClassLibrary1
        Class1.LogIt();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

And the output is

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this case : Project C is referenced in Project A. But still i need to get Project C in the log not Project A when  Project C is calling the method WriteLog(). I tested with Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString(), i am getting Project A name when Project C calls the writelog().

Comment: @KumarSubramanian I have updated the answer for the multi reference scenario, explained by you.

Comment: @KumarSubramanian I have tested that code on my local machine. What is the result you get?

Comment: I was creating trace writer while initializing the log in Project A and I was not doing the same with Project C so that i didn't get any trace output for that project.